# Possible to share internet connection of Management interface of XenServer to VMs?

Tags: xenserver

Is it Possible to share internet connection of Management interface of XenServer to VMs? Problem is that i only can have one physical NIC in my server due to limitation of my provider. So i am left with multiple IPs on management interface, but is it possible to share dedicated IP from a pool (through management interface) towards VMs inside XenServer?

Comment: `Is it Possible to share internet connection of Management interface of XenServer to VMs?` - Probably.

Comment: Cant your providor provide two ethernet connections to your system at all?

Comment: what do you mean? yes, it is possible to have another NIC, but it wont have internet.